# Embedding journalContent theme in liferay 7.4 DXP

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-theme

I am embedding a web content in the theme in liferay 7.4 DXP.

When I embed my 'com_liferay_journal_content_web_portlet_JournalContentPortlet' nothing appears in the theme, the jquery event does activate the div but the configuration 'portlet-topper' does not appear to add the corresponding web content.

```
  <#assign preferences = {
          "portletSetupPortletDecoratorId": "barebone"
          }
      />

      <@liferay_portlet["runtime"]
      defaultPreferences="${freeMarkerPortletPreferences.getPreferences(preferences)}"
      portletProviderAction=portletProviderAction.VIEW
      instanceId="journal_content_name"
      portletName="com_liferay_journal_content_web_portlet_JournalContentPortlet" />
      <#assign preferences = {} />
```

It works perfectly for me if I put any of the other id's from the liferay documentation (https://learn.liferay.com/dxp/latest/en/building-applications/developing-a-java-web-application/reference/portlet-ids.html?highlight=com_liferay_journal_content_web_portlet_journalcontentportlet)

If I add the Publisher asset ID it works perfectly. What is the problem?

Thank you very much for the help